# Add new value to an existing array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In PHP, I'd do something like:

```
$array = array();
$array[] = "value1";
$array[] = "value2";
$array[] = "value3";
```

How would I do the same thing in JavaScript?

Comment: jQuery is not a language; JavaScript is.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Comment: @ChrisB - for those wondering, Javascript is the language used to implement the glorious JQuery.

Comment: I am the only one allowed to decide on the attribution of adjectives to nouns.

Comment: you can use a function for dynamic solution:
animationList[addkey()]
  function addkey()
        {
    var t=ac;
    ac++;
   console.log(t);
    return t;
  }

Answer (score 406, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that. Use regular javascript

```
var arr = new Array();
// or var arr = [];
arr.push('value1');
arr.push('value2');
```

Note: In javascript, you can also use Objects as Arrays, but still have access to the Array prototypes. This makes the object behave like an array:

```
var obj = new Object();
Array.prototype.push.call(obj, 'value');
```

will create an object that looks like:

```
{
    0: 'value',
    length: 1
}
```

You can access the vaules just like a normal array f.ex `obj[0]`.

Comment: which is exactly how the "jQuery" object returned by `$()` works

Comment: Well, I'm sure there's a plugin which allows you to do that with jQuery :P

Comment: How about `[]` instead of `new Array()` and `{}` instead of `new Object()`...

Comment: @J-P: sure, why not. I'm just trying to be as clear as possible in the example.

Comment: Yeah Russ, that's true. Reading the jQuery source is actually quite pleasant I think.

Comment: @J-P: While most find it preferable to read and write, there is no real benefit to using the literal notation when creating empty containers.

Comment: @Justin: Actually, it's slightly faster: http://mir.aculo.us/2009/12/24/extreme-javascript-performance-video (slide 21 onwards)

Comment: @Inquisitor: Interesting. In my tests, the difference was smaller on average coming in at only 0.001.  I did some tests to measure the difference in time to populate an empty array (`a1 = []`) and a pre-sized array (`a2 = new Array(1024)`), but the literal notation was still faster, which is curious to me.

Answer (score 109):

This has nothing to do with jQuery, just JavaScript in general.

To create an array in JavaScript:

```
var a = [];
```

Or:

```
var a = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
```

To append values on the end of existing array:

```
a.push('value4');
```

To create a new array, you should really use `[]` instead of `new Array()` for the following reasons:

- `new Array(1, 2)` is equivalent to `[1, 2]`, but `new Array(1)` is *not* equivalent to `[1]`. Rather the latter is closer to `[undefined]`, since a single integer argument to the `Array` constructor indicates the desired array length.
- `Array`, just like any other built-in JavaScript class, is not a keyword. Therefore, someone could easily define `Array` in your code to do something other than construct an array.

Comment: +1 for `[]` instead of `new Array()`.

Answer (score 36):

Array is a JavaScript native object, why don't you just try to use the API of it? Knowing API on its own will save you time when you will switch to pure JavaScript or another framework.

There are number of different possibilities, so, use the one which mostly targets your needs.

Creating array with values:

```
var array = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
```

Adding values to the end

```
var array = [];
array.push("value1");
array.push("value2");
array.push("value3");
```

Adding values to the begin:

```
var array = [];
array.unshift("value1");
array.unshift("value2");
array.unshift("value3");
```

Adding values at some index:

```
var array = [];
array[index] = "value1";
```

or by using splice

```
array.splice(index, 0, "value1", "value2", "value3");
```

Choose one you need.

Comment: The one with indexes is not working for me. I am using it inside a map function $('select[id^="filter_"]').map(function () { 
                var name = $(this).prop('name');  
                filters[name] = $(this).val();

Answer (score 14):

There are several ways:

**Instantiating the array:**

```
var arr;

arr = new Array(); // empty array

// ---

arr = [];          // empty array

// ---

arr = new Array(3);
alert(arr.length);  // 3
alert(arr[0]); // undefined

// ---

arr = [3];
alert(arr.length);  // 1
alert(arr[0]); // 3
```

**Pushing to the array:**

```
arr = [3];     // arr == [3]
arr[1] = 4;    // arr == [3, 4]
arr[2] = 5;    // arr == [3, 4, 5]
arr[4] = 7;    // arr == [3, 4, 5, undefined, 7]

// ---

arr = [3];
arr.push(4);        // arr == [3, 4]
arr.push(5);        // arr == [3, 4, 5]
arr.push(6, 7, 8);  // arr == [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Using `.push()` is the better way to add to an array, since you don't need to know how many items are already there, and you can add many items in one function call.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `.push()` method (which is standard JavaScript)

e.g.

```
var primates = new Array();
primates.push('monkey');
primates.push('chimp');
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, you must initialize your array then right after that use array.push() command line.

```
var array = new Array();
array.push("first value");
array.push("second value");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

it's not so much jquery as javascript

Comment: that's not *adding* any values to an array, that's creating an array with some values already in it.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote for that, but thanks for at least explaining your opinion

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is an abstraction of JavaScript. Think of jQuery as a sub-set of JavaScript, aimed at working with the DOM. That being said; there are functions for adding item(s) to a collection. I would use basic JavaScript in your case though:

```
var array;

array[0] = "value1";
array[1] = "value2";
array[2] = "value3";
```

... Or:

```
var array = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
```

... Or:

```
var array = [];

array.push("value1");
array.push("value2");
array.push("value3");
```

Comment: I'd call it a "framework"... and it's not a subset either.

Comment: You should initialize the `array` variable to an `Array` object in your first example, otherwise it will be `undefined` and you can't call `push` on it.

Comment: @Ionut G. Stan: I am initializing the array by doing `var array = [];`

Comment: @Mark: I'd call jQuery a library. It is advertised as such and not as a framework.

Comment: @roosteronacid, I meant the first example. I don't know how that `push` observation slipped in my previous comment. I somehow mixed the first and the third examples.