# How to add a new object (key-value pair) to an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I have an array as :

```
items=[{'id':1},{'id':2},{'id':3},{'id':4}];
```

How should I add a new pair `{'id':5}` to the array?

Comment: Thanks @NDM for comment. I tried some code on jsfiddle and it is working (with items.push({'id':5})....) But when I use the same code, the browser shows {{item.id}} instead of showing the updated value of items (I am using angularjs btw). I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add new value to an existing array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996747/add-new-value-to-an-existing-array-in-javascript)

Comment: The OP is creating an array of objects, not an array of values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use [.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
items.push({'id':5});
```

Comment: how can i add it at particular position in the array? say add it at index 3

Comment: @separ1 arr[2] = "name";

Comment: @Shmulik That will replace position 2 rather than add it there. You actually want arr.splice(3, 0, {'id': 3})

Answer (score 12):

[.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will add elements to the end of an array.

Use [.unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) if need to add some element to the beginning of array i.e:

```
items.unshift({'id':5});
```

**Demo:**

```js
items = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}];
items.unshift({'id': 0});
console.log(items);
```

And use [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in case you want to add object at a particular index i.e:

```
items.splice(2, 0, {'id':5});
           // ^ Given object will be placed at index 2...
```

**Demo:**

```js
items = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}];
items.splice(2, 0, {'id': 2.5});
console.log(items);
```

Comment: May I know how to add [{'id': 1,'newId': 'x' }, {'id': 2,'newId': 'y'}, {'id': 3,'newId': 'z'}] ?

Comment: @Codenewbie Sorry, I didn't get your question. It would be great if you please create some working example with expected sample data and expected output.

Comment: sure , i would ask

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes [.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is better than [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) since [.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns the new array whereas [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the length of the array.

Therefore, if you are setting a variable equal to the result, use [.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
items = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}];
newArray = items.push({'id':5})
```

In this case, *newArray* will return 5 (the length of the array).

```
newArray = items.concat({'id': 5})
```

However, here *newArray* will return [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}, {'id': 5}].

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing jQuery, and you've got a [serializeArray](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serializearray.asp) thing going on concerning your form data, such as :

```
var postData = $('#yourform').serializeArray();

// postData (array with objects) : 
// [{name: "firstname", value: "John"}, {name: "lastname", value: "Doe"}, etc]
```

...and you need to add a key/value to this array with the same structure, for instance when posting to a PHP ajax request then this :

```
postData.push({"name": "phone", "value": "1234-123456"});
```

Result:

```
// postData : 
// [{name: "firstname", value: "John"}, {name: "lastname", value: "Doe"}, {"name":"phone","value":"1234-123456"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

New solution with ES6

Default object

```
object = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}];
```

Another object

```
object =  {'id': 5};
```

Object assign ES6

```
resultObject = {...obj, ...newobj};
```

Result

```
[{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}, {'id': 5}];
```

Comment: Please make your answer more elaborate. Explain how it works.

Comment: I think it should be `ary1 = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}];ary2 = [{'id': 3}];join = [...ary1,...ary2];`