# In JavaScript, which is the more efficient way of adding a new element to an array?

Tags: javascript

This is a very simple question. When adding elements to the end of a JavaScript array, do either of these forms have a speed or other optimization benefit over the other? Or does it not really matter, other than style?

(1) pageData[pageData.length] = theMember;

(2) pageData.push(theMember);

Comment: Why bother? You wouldn't notice the change anyway, I'd go for number 2.

Comment: it's not about performance only but push is better, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996747/add-new-value-to-an-existing-array-in-javascript

Comment: I think this question is stated incorrectly. It doesn't make sense to compare single push vs. length instructions, because both take nanoseconds. Performance only matters when you add elements in a loop and in such a case, `push` must be measured against functions that add/create multiple array elements at once, like `concat`, `split`, `match`.

Comment: I was, indeed, adding elements in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tests yielded the following results in the following browsers:

**Array.push**

- Google Chrome 6.0.472.63: **0.4 ms**
- Mozilla Firefox 3.6.10: 5 ms
- Apple Safari 5.0 (7533.16): 2 ms
- Internet Explorer 8: 21.7 ms
- Internet Explorer 7: 66.7 ms
- Opera 10.62: 2.7 ms

**array[array.length]**

- Google Chrome 6.0.472.63: 1.2 ms
- Mozilla Firefox 3.6.10: **0.9 ms**
- Apple Safari 5.0 (7533.16): **0.9 ms**
- Internet Explorer 8: 10.9 ms
- Internet Explorer 7: 32.6 ms
- Opera 10.62: 1 ms

The results speak for themselves: using an index outperforms using Push in every browser with the exception of Google's own. If cross-compatibility is a big concern for you, the utilitarian approach would be to use an index wherever possible.

Source: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2010/10/15/javascript-array-performance.html

Comment: Please don't use link only answers - if the link becomes broken / page is moved then your answer won't be of use.

Comment: Nevertheless, interesting results. Thanks!